# Wizard-style activities and onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, savestate

I implemented several activities in a "wizard-style", that is, there's a next and a previous button at the bottom to navigate between them using:

```
Intent NextActivityIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FormN.class);
startActivity(NextActivityIntent);
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I go back to an Activity, the fields completed previously are empty.

The question is, is there a simpler way to keep displaying the field values other than intercepting the onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState events and save/restore every field manually ?

Comment: dont finish the current activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **startActivityForResult** instead of startActivity. The previous activity and its state would remain in the stack. For going back from your current activity use **finish()**.

Ideally, you should code for onSaveInstanceState in case the phone gets re-oriented. Doesn't matter if you lock your phone orientation though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't think this works for a wizard-like set of activities, because I must be able to go from let's say the third screen back to the first mantaining the data in between. If I go finish()ing them when I go back to the third one it will be empty.

Comment: In that case you don't have to even finish any of the activities. You can reorder your activities using an Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. In your example, this will bring back the 3rd activity if it was already running. You will have to look into the exact details of implementing this. I think you can use a ViewFlipper rather than creating new activities. Will be much simpler.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I'll ask about cross-validation in another thread.